# Access Control on SOS Berlin JobScheduler

Tags: authentication, job-scheduling

I am working on SOS Berlin JobScheduler but unable to find a way to enable access control on the Dashboard,Object Editor or JobScheduler's Browser UI.

Is there a way to enable the same so that JobScheduler asks for authentication details when a user hits http://hostnameofjobscheduler:port ?

I refered SOS Security Server from the below link:
http://www.sos-berlin.com/doc/en/sossecure.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about authentication with

- the Browser UI (JOC) is provided with the article [How to configure JOC for HTTP authentication](https://kb.sos-berlin.com/x/u4I3).
- the Dashboard (JID) is provided by the document that you are referring to. Are you missing something?
- the Object Editor (JOE) is not provided. The Apache Shiro interface (as used by JID) will be used starting from release 1.10. As a workaround to restrict user access you could use file permissions or use the built-in FTP/SFTP client for user based authentication or public/private key based authentication.